# React - use variable as value for HTML element and change it's value when variable changes

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm trying to achieve the following:
1.) Create a variable X containing some text.
2.) Create HTML element (paragraph) which displays text from variable.
3.) Have an HTML Input field to change the variable X content.
4.) Once content of the variable X changes, display updated value/text in the paragraph where it was previously displayed.

I have the following code which seems to log into the console the new value after change, but the paragraph is not updated with the new variable's value:

```
import './App.css';
import Input from '@material-ui/core/Input'

function App() {
  let X = 'My text 1';

  const handleChangeInputField = (event) => {
    valueOfInputField = event.target.value
    console.log(valueOfInputField)
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Input onChange={ handleChangeInputField } />
      <p>{ X }</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Any ideas why my `<p>` element is not updated when the variable X's value is changed?

Thank you

Comment: As the answer states, you need to use state. But nothing in this code changes the value of X, either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reactjs listens for state changes, not variable value changes. You should use `useState` hook here. Read more about it here: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

```
const [x, setX] = useState('Some text');
...
const handleInputChange = (event) => {
  setX(event.currentTarget.value);
}
...
```

By the way, your `handleInputChange` function should be a `useCallback` hook IMO:

```
const handleInputChange = useCallback((event) => {
  setX(event.currentTarget.value);
}, []);
```

Comment: Thank you, this explained and solved the issue.
One question though, what is the difference between using `useCallback` and not using it?

Comment: Usually React caches functions, so for example if you would use your state variable in a vanilla function - it value would not change if that function. If you use useCallback and add your state variable in the dependency array `}, [x]);`, the function would be recached when your state variables' value changes. Hope that clears it up.